# Insert custom value as first item in ngselect angular package

Tags: angular

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select for autocomplete cum dropdown. How to insert something like "Please select" as the very first element in it.

i implemented the package as follow. This is my html file

```
<ng-select class="custom" [items]="items"
           bindLabel="Name"
           autofocus
           bindValue="Id"
           (close)="close()"
           (clear)="clear()"
           placeholder="Select people"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedId">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From there demo page, use **placeholder="Select age"**

```
<ng-select #agesSelect [items]="ages"
   [selectOnTab]="true"
   bindValue="value"
   labelForId="age"
   (ngModelChange)="showConfirm(confirmation)"
   placeholder="Select age"
   formControlName="age">
```

Code: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fforms-single-select-example.component.html

Demo: https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/forms

Comment: i tried it already. updated question to show my implementation. can you tell me what am i doing incorrect.

Comment: My bad. its working. but its not working in one page. i will figure it out. thanks.